# Pending Request/Accept System in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, request

I am trying to create a hospital/user system where the user can request the specific hospital if the blood sample is available.
So the logic is:I will store three id's of user,blood & hospital in the 'request' table, later I will fetch name from other table using a join query.
(please tell me if any other way its possible)

Here is my view page (its fetch data from 'blood' table):

```
    <table>

     <?php if(count($blood_all>0))
     { $i=0;
     foreach ($blood_all as $user) {
     $i++;
     ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $user->btype ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $user->detail?></td>
     <td><?php echo $user->hospital_id?></td>
     <td>
              <?= anchor("Property/blood_req/{$user->id}",'Request', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
     </td>

     </tr>
     <?php }
     }?>
     </table>
```

so when user press request it will send id of blood table(if I am right)

if user is not login he/she will have to login, after that he/she can send a request: 
Please note that:I already have hospital_id in my blood table, So I will only have to store user_id, so admin will know that which user is sending a request.

Here is my controller:

```
   public function blood_req($blood_id)
      {
        if(!$this->session->userdata('user_id'))
         {
           return redirect('Login/loginview_load');
          }
         else {
           $this->load->model('Partner_model');
           $data['blood']=$this->Partner_model->find_blood($blood_id);
           $user =$this->session->userdata('user_id');
          $user_data = array(
            'blood_id' =>$this->input->post($data['id']) ,
            'hospital_id' =>$this->input->post($data['hospital_id']) ,
            'user_id' =>$user
           );
            if($this->Partner_model->req_send($user_data))
          {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login','Request sent Successfully');
            return redirect('Property/available');
          }
          else {
            echo "fail";
          }


         }
      }
```

and here is my model:

```
   public function find_blood($blood_id)
  {
    $q=$this->db->select('*')
    ->where('id',$blood_id)
    ->get('blood');
    return $q->row();
  }
 public function req_send($data)
  {
   return $this->db->insert('request',$data);
  }
```

When I press request its print 'fail' which means data was not inserted in the request table.

Comment: Can you show us your `database table structure`? Also what you are getting in your `$data` before `$user_data` line.

Comment: @Yogendrasinh I have 4 tables (user,blood,request,hospital) in blood table I have 4 column (id,blood_type,detail & hospital_id) & request table have 4 column which is all INT type it will only store id(id,user_id,blood_id & hospital_id)

Comment: @Yogendrasinh if I print_r($data) , its shows : Array ( [blood] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [btype] => a [detail] => asdf [hospital_id] => 1 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing directly the values. use below code to access your array values. As you given data in comment, it shows your `blood` array is `stdClass Object` so you have to access it using `->`.

```
$user_data = array(
    'blood_id' =>$data['blood']->id,
    'hospital_id' =>$data['blood']->hospital_id ,
    'user_id' =>$user
);
```

Comment: its working now,thanks.  Can you please tell me is it a right way to create request/accept system?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR You said you are sending `blood id` to controller function but i see in your code you are sending `user id` using this line `<?= anchor("Property/blood_req/{$user->id}",'Request', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>`. Other then it is correct way to request for blood and accepting it as my point of view.